# .bashrc commands are echoing to terminal. Can I stop this

Tags: bash, echo

I have two commands added to my .bashrc file  "ifup eno1"   and   "ifup eno2".
When a terminal is opened the results of both of these commands are echoed to the terminal.  Is there a way to turn of the echo just for these two commands?    Actually I would like to execute these commands only once, but they execute each time a terminal is opened (like it's supposed to do)  I don't think it is a good idea to open these network ports over and over again.  Is there an "if" statement that can go in the .bashrc that will only execute these commands if the ports are NOT already active.

Thanks all for any help.

Comment: Which OS/distribution and version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redirect the command output of those 2 command to `/dev/null`, like this:

```sh
ifup eno1 > /dev/null
```

See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119648/redirecting-to-dev-null) for more information.